# How many strings of length $10$, with letters taken from $\{A, B, C, D, E\}$, contain at least $1$ $A$ and at least $1$ $B$?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

How many strings of length $10$ exist?
For each position in the string we have $5$ choices
That's $5^{10}$

How many strings of length $10$ with no $A$'s exist?
For each position in the string we have $4$ choices
That's $4^{10}$

How many strings of length $10$ with no $B$'s exist?
For each position in the string we have 4 choices
That's $4^{10}$

How many strings of length $10$ with no $A$'s and no $B$'s exist?
For each position in the string we have $3$ choices
That's $3^{10}$

Now we need to subtract the number of "no $A$ no $B$" strings from the number of "no $A$" strings to get the number of "no $A$ and at least $1$ $B$" strings
$4^{10} - 3^{10}$

And we need to subtract the number of "no $A$ no $B$" strings from the number of "no $B$" strings to get the number of "no $B$ and at least $1$ $A$" strings
$4^{10} - 3^{10}$

Now we need to subtract the number of
"no $A$ and no $B$" strings and the number of "no $A$ and at least $1$ $B$" strings and the number of "no $B$ and at least $1$ $A$ strings" from the total number of length $10$ strings

So the answer is : $$5^{10} - (4^{10} - 3^{10}) - (4^{10} - 3^{10}) - (3^{10})$$ 
or $$5^{10} - 4^{10} - 4^{10} + 3^{10} + 3^{10} - 3^{10}$$

so $$5^{10} - 2 * 4^{10} + 3^{10}$$

Comment: Your solution is correct. It is an application of the Inclusion-exclusion principle.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  To get your formatting to come out correctly, you have to enclose the expressions in `$` signs. So `$5^3$` will be formatted as $5^3$.